# RS 232 Communication in ASP.NET 3.5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, serial-port, communication

using ASP.NET 3.5 WebForm using C# 3.0, is it possible to setup a RS 232 communication with a device? I need the WebForm to be able to read and write data to the serial port. I would appreciate if there are some good examples, thanks.

I understand that under Components, there is a SerialPort .NET Component, but it seems to me that it can only be used in a Windows application (WinForm).

Or the only solution is to rely on the ActiveComport Serial Port Toolkit, as from http://www.activexperts.com/activcomport/howto/aspnetc/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your situation is

(A.web client) <--http-->  (B.iis/asp.net) --serial link--> (C.some device)

The good news is there are solutions without controls. 
See this [MSDN Magazine article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301786.aspx) or this [Codeguru Article](http://www.codeguru.com/Csharp/Csharp/cs_network/remoting/article.php/c6015/)

Two issues.

1. You are calling native code so you need full trust.
2. You cannot monitor the device(C) for replies